# Android: LinearLayout Rearranged when updating views

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I'm having a problem with a LinearLayout in an app i'm working on. The linear layout is vertical. There are several items in the layout including a TextView, a vertical SeekBar,  and an ImageView.

Whenever I update the textView (ie setText()) my layout rearranges. The ImageView goes from being at the bottom to being in the middle. Same thing happens if I replace the drawable in the ImageView.

I assume I have something wrong with how I am specifying my layout. This is the portion having problems:

```
        <modrobotics.code.ui.BlockValueSliderView
            android:id="@+id/sliderSix"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-12dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/BVLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:paddingTop="12dp"
                android:text="64"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="20sp" >
            </TextView>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/circle1"
                android:layout_width="6dp"
                android:layout_height="6dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="-6dp"
                android:background="@drawable/circle"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="0dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/controlElementList12"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="0dp" >

                <modrobotics.code.ui.VerticalSeekBar
                    android:id="@+id/slider"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="-20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="20"
                    android:padding="0dp"
                    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_progress"
                    android:thumb="@drawable/seekbar_thumb"
                    android:thumbOffset="-1dp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/logo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="-20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:padding="0dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/on6" >
                </ImageView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </modrobotics.code.ui.BlockValueSliderView>
```

EDIT:

I have tried the suggestions mentioned below to no avail. I have removed all negative margins, simplified the layout by removing unnecessary LinearLayout, gotten rid of GONE, fixed height for images etc...  I'm starting to believe the problem is greater than just this.

I'm using a single Activity with a PageAdapter. It seems I'm not using PageAdapter correctly. startUpdate() is being called over and over again. Any static global variables I have seem be cleaned up or on separate threads some how. I believe these problems may all be linked. Perhaps I don't full understand the threading model when using a PageAdapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a problem related to the VerticalSeekBar implementation I was using.

I was rotating the thumb for the seekbar, and also calling bringToFront() on the seekbar. The combination of these two calls caused elements to be rearranged. Not to sure why, but removing these two lines of code fixed my problems.

Answer (score 0):

In 'modrobotics.code.ui.BlockValueSliderView' change the visiblity from GONE to INVISIBLE. It's possible that the layout elements will re-arrange whenever you change the visibility programatically from GONE to VISIBLE of this View because while the View is set to be GONE, it doesn't occupy any space in the layout and rest of the Views are placed in the layout just taking its space. If it's GONE, It behaves like it doesn't exist in the layout. Then, when you sets this view to be VISIBLE, it switches rest of the Views in the layout to prepare a space for itslef.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have changed gone to invisible for all elements. Unfortunately the problem still exists. It seems to be `controlElementList12` LinearLinear layout whose children flip flop.

Comment: In your ImageView logo try to set height to 0dp since you have already set weight to 1

Comment: Also try to avoid using negative margins